# B2C API connector is not called

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have integrated API connector on an Azure B2C Sign Up User Flow to enrich token with a custom attribute from a REST API call. Works great! When user log in, custom attribute is correctly present in token.

Then, I have enabled Self-service password reset, following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-user-flow). And now, if during Sign Up journey user clicks on "Forgot your password?" link and changes his password, at the end he get signed up (and password has been changed) but API connector has not been called and custom attribute is not present in token.

Did I miss something or is this scenario not supported by User flows?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

As per docs:

There are three places in a user flow where you can enable an API connector:

- After federating with an identity provider during sign-up - applies to sign-ups experiences only
- Before creating the user - applies to sign-ups experiences only
- Before sending the token (preview) - applies to sign-ups and sign-ins

When you click on "Forgot your password?", this takes you on a different flow.
Not sign-up or sign-in.

Comment: You are right. Therefore I configured my API connector on "Before sending the token (preview)" section to call my API endpoint. "Forgot your password?" may start on a different flow, but at the end it does a sign-in and a token is sent. So, my API connector should be called, no?

Comment: "Forget password" is a different flow. At the end. you may be "signed in" i.e. you receive a JWT but that's not a sign-in flow.

Answer (score 0):

We have just come across this same issue, we had also assumed the API connector would be called following a user changing their password (as this is part of the sign-in flow - we only have this single user flow configured).

Ultimately we are being presented with a token by b2c so the user must have signed in (even though it was via forgotten password). This seems like a missed scenario when the api-connector capability was added?

I can see an issue has been raised against the api-connector samples on GitHub, and the only response is a workaround to forcibly log the user out:

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/api-connector-samples/issues/1

We will continue to look for alternatives, however we may be forced to use this approach as we are dependent on the api-connector being called.